# React useEffect stop infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

This code makes an infinite loop, I need to find a way to fix it.

I want to fill the state moviesinfos with moviesData values to be able to map on it to display cards for each movie.

First, I have tried to setMovieinfos just after the push function but it did not work.
So I thought that it would be nicer to put it into an independant useEffect.

It doesn't seems to be the right way to do that ^^.

```
function App() {

  const [movieid, setMovieid] = useState([]);
  const [movieinfos, setMovieinfos] = useState([]);
  let moviesData = [] 

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.movies)
   
      setMovieid(response.data.movies)
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
     
  
}, []);

console.log(movieid)

useEffect(() => {
for (const movie of movieid) {
console.log(movie.movieid)
 axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${movie.movieid}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=fr`) 

  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    
    
    moviesData.push(
    {Genres: response.data.genres,
      Overview: response.data.overview,
      Poster: response.data.poster_path,
      Company: response.data.production_companies,
      Release: response.data.release_date,
      Title: response.data.title}
      );
              
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })

  }

}, [movieid]);

useEffect(() => {

setMovieinfos (moviesData)
 
}, [moviesData]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Header">
        <Logo />
      </div>
      <div className="Menu">
        <Search />
        <Add_movie_button />
        <Delete_movie_button />
        <Random_movie_button />
      </div>
      <div className="Movies">
        
        
        {movieinfos.map((movie) => <Movie_card key={movie.Title} data={movie}/>)}

      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `let moviesData = []` is a **new** array on every render, yet the last `useEffect` depends on it. Meaning it will also run and update the state (`setMovieinfos`) on every render. This is your infinite loop. To help get rid of that, I would need a better understanding of what you're trying to do. Could you clarify your question and possibly add some dummy data?

Comment: The first axios gets IDs from my database.
The second axios uses those IDs to make a request to "the movie database", to collect infos for every movie.

What I want to do is render a card component for each of those movies, with the movie infos in it.

I do all that stuff because I want infos only for the movies I have in the database from the API.

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this in one operation?

Comment: I tried to directly setState instead of putting things into the moviesData table but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

As Yohsi pointed out, the infinte loop is caused by that useEffect depending on a new array on every rerender.

My advice though is that you should try to keep your components with as least state as posible.

If you don't need to show the `movieid` anywhere, don't set it in a state to be handled by a useEffect later, that just makes it hard to follow.

It looks as if your whole component only would need `moviesInfo` state, where you can handle it in a single useEffect:

```
const [movieinfos, setMovieinfos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000")
    .then(function (response) {
      const movies = response.data.movies;
      return Promise.all(
        movies.map((movie) =>
          axios.get(
            `${BASE_URL}${movie.movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=fr`
          )
        )
      );
    })
    .then((responses) => {
      setMovieinfos(
        responses.map((response) => ({
          Genres: response.data.genres,
          Overview: response.data.overview,
          Poster: response.data.poster_path,
          Company: response.data.production_companies,
          Release: response.data.release_date,
          Title: response.data.title,
        }))
      );
    });
}, []);
```

I'd recommend so much when working with react to avoid using many `useEffect` hooks, specially avoid using them to orchestrate side effects that depend on one another.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot !!

I have to check how the Promise.all works, I don't know that thing ^^